# PL/I & not printing on tab stop

Tags: mainframe, pl-i

I have the following PL/I code:

```
    declare 1 u union,
      2 c character(1),
      2 ci fixed binary(4) unsigned;

    ci = data_mem(data_ptr);
    put list (c);
```

What this does, is it takes an integer and outputs that as if it was an ascii/ebcdic value. So it shows characters. Sofar this works.
The problem now is that each character is printed at an 24 spaces interval, as if 3 TABs are inserted.
I tried converting c to a string first and then applying trim() but that did not help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the default PUT LIST behavior for a PRINT-attribute file. From the IBM Enterprise PL/I for z/OS Language Reference, under Stream-oriented Data Transmission -> LIST -> PUT list-directed (emphasis mine):

> The values of the data-list items are converted to character representations (except for graphics) and transmitted to the data stream. A blank separates successive data values transmitted. **For PRINT files, items are separated according to program tab settings (see “PRINT attribute”).**

The next manual section discusses the PRINT attribute. Here we have

> Data values transmitted by list- and data-directed data transmission are
>   automatically aligned on the left margin and on implementation-defined preset tab
>   positions.

Since you omitted FILE, your PUT is going to the default FILE(SYSPRINT). SYSPRINT is defined implicitly as FILE ENVIRONMENT(F RECSIZE(121)) OUTPUT PRINT STREAM (see Input and Output -> FILE Attribute -> File constant in the Language Reference, and Defining and Using Consecutive Data Sets -> Using PRINT files with stream I/O in the Programmer's Guide). IIRC, the defaults are every 24, which gives 5 tabs per line, compatible with the old 120-byte printers common in the early days of PL/I F in the late 1960s. This is modifiable by declaring a PLITABS structure (described in the previously mentioned manual section).

LIST- and DATA-directed I/O are intended to be quick & dirty I/O interfaces with little regard for formatting on output (but are very forgiving on input). EDIT is better for formatting output, but it does show a lot of its FORTRAN roots for input and output. Personally, for traditional reports using formatted output, and for record input, I would work with record I/O, which is analogous to standard COBOL I/O.

Comment: This seems to show default tab positions, which agree with what you say: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSY2V3_4.4.0/com.ibm.entpli.doc_4.4/pg/ibma1d51002738.htm#ibma1d51002738__tabsrh

Comment: Thanks for digging that up and reminding me about PLITABS. There's a lot of noise out there for searching this info, which I kept running into. Lots of wheat/chaff separation. I am updating the answer to mention it (it's documented in the same breath as the default SYSPRINT).